# SignalR is sending but not receiving

Tags: reactjs, redux, signalr, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm setting up `SignalR` in my app with `React`, `Redux` frontend. I'm able to send out messages to my hub but when the hub broadcasts messages, I see the following in the console:

> Warning: No client method with the name 'UpdateMessages' found.

Here's what my middleware looks like which is in charge of sitting in between the SignalR hub and my `Redux` store. This code is in a separate file of its own:

```
import * as types from '../../actions/actionTypes';
import * as SignalR from '@aspnet/signalr-client';

// Get the store
import appStore from '../../store/appStore';

// Declare connection
let connection = new SignalR.HubConnection('http://localhost:49065/im', 'formatType=json&format=text');

export const signalRInvokeMiddleware = (store) => (next) => async (action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case types.SIGNALR_SEND_MESSAGE:
            connection.invoke("Send", action.message);
            break;
    }

    return next(action);
}

export const signalRRegisterCommands = (appStore) => {

    connection.on('UpdateMessages', data => {
        debugger;
        appStore.dispatch(updateSignalRMessages(data))
    })

    connection.start();
};

connection.start();
```

Here's what my store code looks like:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/rootReducer';
import { signalRInvokeMiddleware } from '../middleware/signalR/signalRMiddleware';

export default function configureStore(initialState){
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(thunk, signalRInvokeMiddleware)
    );
}
```

And this is what my hub code looks like:

```
public class MyChatHub : Hub
{
    public Task Send(string message)
    {
        return Clients.All.InvokeAsync("UpdateMessages", message);
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I figured out the problem.I had to change my `configureStore()` a bit. See below:

```
export default function configureStore(initialState){
    const store = createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(thunk, signalRInvokeMiddleware)
    );

    signalRRegisterCommands(store);

    return store;
}
```

Comment: Where do you call signalRRegisterCommands?

Comment: That was the problem. I had to change my `configureStore()` method a bit. It works now.